# Why do UI operations run after computations even if the two are alternating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is more complex, but I've arrived at this simple & concise example:

HTML:

```
First: <span id="first"></span> <br/> 
Then: <span id="second"></span> <br/> 
And then: <span id="third"></span> <br/> 
And then: <span id="fourth"></span> <br/> 
And then: <span id="fifth"></span>
```

JS (+jQuery (if matters)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doStuff();
});

function doStuff() {
  $("#first").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  var i = 1;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++;
  }
  $("#second").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  var i = 1;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++;
  }
  $("#third").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  var i = 1;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++;
  }
  $("#fourth").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  var i = 1;
  while (i < 1000000000) {
    i++;
  }
  $("#fifth").text(new Date().getSeconds());
}
```

And [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvnwkn53/).

From this example, my intuition tells me the `$("#first")` should receive its text value way before the `$("#fifth")`. However, they all appear at the same time. And no, it's not a matter of JS running really fast, as you can see in the example that the `$("#first")` has its value ~2 seconds lower than the `$("#fifth")`.

Why is this happening (and what!), and what solution(s) exist?

Comment: thats my output: First: 42 
Then: 42 
And then: 43 
And then: 43 
And then: 44, whats mysterious i cant get u bro

Comment: javascript is single thread language. Your while loops are freezing the UI. Webworkers could be a solution but in fact you cannot access DOM from a worker so it really depends what is your real use case. Using timeout could be an other solution but it would just be a workaround

Comment: I suspect the problem you are seeing is a browser specific bug. With chrome I get First: 38 
Then: 39 
And then: 40 
And then: 41 
And then: 43

Comment: @bhspencer But you get them all at once, not one after other. That's all the question here, if i'm correct: `$("#first") should get its text value way before the $("#fifth")`

Comment: Operators in Javascript be proccess same time not like PHP

Comment: Yes you get them all at once. That is to be expected. The DOM is not reflowed until the end of the JS block.

Comment: If you need the DOM to be updated more frequently you need to devide your code into multiple JS blocks. you can do this with timeouts. The function you pass to each timeout would run as a separate JS block and the DOM would be updated between them.

Comment: You should read about the JavaScript Event Loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please mark it as the correct one - this may help other guys checking this question in the future. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

javascript blocks page rendering, so until all the javascript block is done, it will not render the html output.

Comment: true, but that JS needs to write in the DOM, so the JS is blocking the painting that's happening inside the script, until it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript blocks the UI before it is finished. It is supposed to be a single-threaded language, however (as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734311/5788429)) it is not that simple.

The solution to your problem is to use `setTimeout`. See the [updated simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvnwkn53/1/) (the example is not suitable for copy paste but I believe it is sufficient to present the idea):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doStuff();
});

function doStuff() {
  $("#first").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  var i = 1;

  setTimeout(function() {
    while (i < 1000000000) {
      i++;
    }
    $("#second").text(new Date().getSeconds());
  }, 0);
}
```

The `setTimeout` ensures that the `doStuff` functions finishes, the browser then processes the DOM changes and then the other function (passed to the `setTimeout` method) is executed.

A nice and succinct explanation of why things happen this way can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) (thank you [@bhspencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556520/bhspencer) for providing the link). Simply and shortly: While JS is processing the `doStuff` method, the UI is blocked (due to its single-threaded nature). The call to `setTimeout` with second parameter set to 0 milliseconds puts (immediately) into the processing queue another piece of code (first parameter of `setTimeout`). Then the `doStuff` method finishes. JS then processes next item from the queue - which is apparently the UI update. Again, when UI update is finished, next item in the queue is what was added there by the `setTimout` call.

Comment: Some explanation of why setTimeout ensures that the doStull finishes would improve this answer. Some mention of the javascript event loop might help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop